# Let $S = \{A : A \subseteq \mathbb{Z}^+, |A| < \infty\}$. Prove or disprove $|S| = |\mathbb{Z}|$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

If it were $\mathbb{R}$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}$, I could figure it out: just construct $2$ bijections. 
For example, map $\mathbb{R}$ to $(0,1)$ and then map $(0,1)$ to $\mathbb{R}$ in tangent function. However, when it comes to a set with discrete elements, this method doesn't work. 
Is there any other ways?

Comment: What do you think? If you think that $|S|=|\mathbb Z|$, then fining a bijection would still be the way to go.

Comment: These two links have infinitely many more possible duplicate suggestions under "Linked" and "Related" in the part to the right of the question.